# Cordova Geolocation load after all the element

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am facing issue with cordova geolocation. It is taking time to return the value. I used the timeout but it is not working as expected. I can't put too much time to the user to wait on.

Here is the code.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
   $scope.userlongitude = position.coords.longitude;
   $scope.userlatitude = position.coords.latitude;

   console.log($scope.userlatitude);
   console.log($scope.userlongitude);                             
});
```

Here is the Ajax code where I am using geolocation.

```
$timeout(function() {
   $http({
      url: 'suggestions.php',
      method: "GET",
      params: {
         latitude: $scope.userlatitude,
         longitude: $scope.userlongitude
      }
   })
   .success(function(data) {
      $scope.news_suggestions = data.content;
   });
}, 3000);
```

Above code where i used http request fire before the geolocations return.

How to fix the issues.

Edit:

I tried device ready event but issue not resolved.

```
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
     function onDeviceReady() {
     -------- Codes are here. ----------
    }
});
```

Comment: You can call this on device ready event

Comment: I tried device ready event but issue still there. Ajax fired before the geolocation send the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition
Please use the default callback function

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);

    var options = {};

    function success(position) {
      $scope.userlongitude = position.coords.longitude;
      $scope.userlatitude = position.coords.latitude;

      $http({
          url: 'suggestions.php',
          method: "GET",
          params: {
             latitude: $scope.userlatitude,
             longitude: $scope.userlongitude
          }
       })
       .success(function(data) {
          $scope.news_suggestions = data.content;
       });
    }

    function error(err) {
      console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
    }
```